# drush uli command goes to wrong domain

Tags: drush

I'm new to the command line, having trouble understanding why the uli drush command is taking me to the wrong domain.

On Pantheon, the dev site address is: dev-example.pantheon.io

I've successfully installed drush and all the aliases I need. However, when I enter this command:

```
drush @pantheon.example.dev uli
```

It takes me to wrong domain: wrongsite.com/user/reset/1/1....A/login

It should be: dev-example.pantheon.io/user/reset/1/1....A/login

I can login as user1 if correct the domain in the address bar. But what's happening here and how do I fix default domain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one was more obvious than I thought. Client added bogus domains to the dev environment which caused the uli to go to the wrong site.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this using Drush 5, 6 and 7 on Pantheon (using Drush 7 locally), and also Drush 5, 6 and 7 locally (using Drush 7 on Pantheon), and all of those combinations worked for me.

Drush decides what domain to use by consulting the value of the --uri option.  This is provided by the Pantheon aliases that you downloaded, so you might want to try downloading them again, just in case something is wrong in the alias file.

To test the alias, try `drush @pantheon.example.dev status`, and check the value of the `Site URI` line.

To select which version of Drush you are using, see [this blog post on Drush policy files](https://pantheon.io/blog/fix-drush-site-aliases-policy-file).  Note that you must be using Drush 7 locally for this technique to work.